# Restore deleted _thumbnail_id in postmeta table

Tags: post-meta

Alright - so I was missing a bunch of 'featured images' so I did a DB delete of a bunch of postmeta rows with the meta_key = "_thumbnail_id". Unfortunately, my query was a little greedier than I thought.

So I restored the rows that I deleted (I backed up those specific rows) but the thumbnails have not returned.

I'm no wordpress master, so I'm wondering if there is something else that I need to restore to get those references back.

Comment: It's not really clear which the problem is. Thumbnails reference are not in DB? They are but the images are not shown? Are you sure that post rows referenced in `_thumbnail_id` exist? Are you sure that the images exists in the path they are supposed to be?

Comment: @gmazzap So I deleted rows with the meta_key of "_thumbnail_id". I restored those rows exactly, but now the features images no longer appear to be attached to the original posts. That make sense?

Comment: The value of "_thumbnail_id" is the ID of a row in the _posts_ table. Even if the rows with the meta_key "_thumbnail_id" are there, if the post rows are not there, WordPress can't show the images. Also, are you sure tha tthe images are physically in the path?

Comment: yes, positive the images are still in the path. Are there foreign keys that cause posts to be deleted automatically? Otherwise, they should still be there, right?

Comment: @gmazzap just verified that the posts referenced still exist. But still no 'featured image'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow in the import process a trailing space was added to the meta_key (making it "_thumbnail_id "). Mysql apparently matches on a trailing space which is why it wasn't apparent, but once I removed the space all featured images started showing again.